# In android, how to listen to gestures on an ImageView?

Tags: android

I would like to define an ImageView in Xml, and then listen to gestures which occur only on that ImageView.  But, it appears that the constructor for GestureDector requires an Activity as a parameter, and then responds to gesture events on all components in that Activity.  Is there any way to limit this such that events are only generated for gestures upon the pre-defined ImageView?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

extend `ImageView` and make it implement `OnGestureListener`
`

Comment: but... I don't see how this can be done with an ImageView which I defined and laid out in XML?

Comment: you can give a full class name in the xml layout <com.example.widgets.MyImageView>  or  <View class="com.example.widgets.MyImageView" />